# scrollTop within div not working with onclick on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I searched around net and tried many things but scrollTop is scrolling randomly.
I want to scroll within a div when clicked on links.

My div:

```
<div id="test" style="height:400px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <img src="basjhdba1.jpg" id="item_1">
    //longtext here
    <img src="basjhdba2.jpg" id="item_2">
    //longtext here
    <img src="basjhdba3.jpg" id="item_3">
    //longtext here
</div>
```

Three links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeItemDisplay(1)">Item 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeItemDisplay(2)">Item 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeItemDisplay(3)">Item 3</a>
```

The onclick method:

```
changeItemDisplay: function(a)
{
    var target = "#item_"+a;

    $("#dishesresults").stop().animate({scrollTop: ($(target).position().top)+"px"}, 800);
}
```

This is not working correctly, but they have some pattern there for scrolling. Even if I click one link twice consecutively then also it is moving every time.
Don't know what is causing this.

Comment: I updated it, still not working. @Teemu

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, but the problem still exists. @A.Wolff

Comment: Indeed, too many things wrong there. What about debuging your code opening your console??? And please, stop tag spamming

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried debugging all things running fine. But when I tried to know the '$(target).position().top' value, its coming different everytime. I also tried offset instead of position.

Comment: Please add more code so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: ↑↑↑ and maybe provide a jsFiddle

Comment: I don't have the time to finish this, but here's something you guys can work with: http://jsfiddle.net/n70amcaj/ @A.Wolff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div is scrolling randomly, because you don't check its position.

You need to know number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area ([scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)) and current position of the `$('#test')` relative to the document ([offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)).

As a side note: better idea is to use jQuery's [**`.click()`**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method instead of binding event handler with `onclick` *event attribute*, [*and this is why.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/wLe4aox1/) (used Bram Vanroy template)

```
<a href="#item_1" class="changeItem">Item 1</a>
<a href="#item_2" class="changeItem">Item 2</a>
<a href="#item_3" class="changeItem">Item 3</a>

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('.changeItem').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#test').stop().animate({
                scrollTop:  $('#test').scrollTop() - $('#test').offset().top + $(target).offset().top
            }, 800);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Finally someone with answer. Thank you so much. You are awesome :)